# How to move stepper buttons to the top of the steps

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building a stepper form and need the buttons to be at the top right of the steps instead of the bottom left. I have gotten them to move to the bottom right but can't seem to find a way to move them to the top.

Here are the onStep button functions currently active

```html
 onStepContinue: () {
            final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;
            bool Step = true;
            int i = 1;

            listDynamic.forEach((widget) {
              if(widget.lengthFT.text == '' && widget.lengthIN.text == '' && Step == true){
                if(isLastStep){
                  print('Complete');
                  //Send Data to Database
                }
                else{
                  setState(() {
                    currentStep += 1;
                    Step = false;
                  });
                }
              }
              else if(listDynamic.length == i){
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                  msg: 'ERROR: Last entry has not been saved. Please save entry!',
                  webPosition: "center",
                  webBgColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #dc1c13, #B90E0A)",
                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              }
              i++;
            });


        },
        onStepCancel:
          currentStep == 0 ? null : () => setState(() => currentStep -= 1),

            controlsBuilder: ((context, details) {
              final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;
              
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [ 
                      if(currentStep != 0)
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: const Text('BACK'),
                          onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 12,),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text(isLastStep ? 'CONFIRM' : 'NEXT'),
                          onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
            }
```

I tried using crossAxisAlignment and wrapping the container in an Align widget. Neither of which worked.

Comment: You either need to wrap the Stepper widget with some other widget (like stack or row) to place your buttons in the top right, or implement your own Stepper.

Comment: @GregoryConrad The entire Stepper needs to be wrapped or just the step?

Comment: @GregoryConrad I tried wrapping the entire Stepper in both a Stack and row and neither moved the buttons towards the top.

Comment: sorry wasn’t clear. Wrap the Stepper in a row or stack (depending on how it looks) along with the buttons directly in the row/Stack. The stepper should have no buttons being built in the controlsBuilder

Comment: @GregoryConrad Could I possibly get an example of this? I am not sure exactly where to put the cancel button if its not ment to be in the controlsBuilder

Comment: Something like:
```Stack(children: [
  Stepper(
    /* ... */
    controlsBuilder: (_, __) => SizedBox.shrink(),
  ),
  /* Your own buttons go here */
]),
```

Comment: Except, it probably would just be worth it to implement your own Stepper. You are really fighting what it is designed to do here.